# BIOS only allows UEFI No Legacy Option

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, bios

Laptop: Lenova Yoga 2.11

I am running Windows 10 Build 10041.
I have bought a new copy of Win 8.1, which I want to clean instal.
However, my BIOS has no option to change from UEFI to Legacy so that I can boot from USB Flash Drive or Disc.

Only one Boot Mode given: UEFI. No BIOS updates available from Lenova for this machine either.

Any solution to this?

Comment: You don't have to switch, to install 8.1, so why are you?

Comment: @Ramhound, She thinks she cannot boot from Usb flash or disk. Surely the bios has a hotkey for a boot menu, F12 i think.

Comment: @Moab I think I know the reason want to hear it from the horses mouth

Comment: @Ramhound, already did "so that I can boot from USB Flash Drive or Disc."

Comment: @Moab - I still maintain you don't have to switch to legacy mode to boot EFI media, infact if you do switch, its guaranteed you can't switch to EFI media since you would be booting in legacy mode.

Comment: BIOS is not needed to boot from a flash drive. You just need a UEFI boot disk

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change to legacy. Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a GPT/UEFI compatible USB thumb drive from your Windows 8.1 ISO.

Answer (score -2):

regarding your problem this might be helpful:

- Check the options in the firmware menus to enable or disable BIOS-compatibility mode.
- To use BIOS-compatibility mode, check for options in the firmware menus to disable UEFI SecureBoot features.

---

Else, try to run setup while you are using any OS preinstalled; I think it will prompt direct install via restarting machine.
Also to prevent Windows Setup or Windows PE from booting in UEFI mode, remove the **efi** folder on the root of the media.